# Linux Filesystem Tree

Tags: linux, filesystems, tree

Is there a pictorial representation of Linux filesystem, to understand the Linux filesystem.  Currently running Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to efficiently re-install, using 2 HDD, 1x250GB and 1x500GB.  The 250GB being the faster drive.

Comment: Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 13):

Currently **FileSystem Hierarchy Standard** (FHS) is in version **2.3**. To get an in-depth knowledge about it, Visit [this page](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ab/06/70/ab0670ef648900b04d7a37d7a5b5ba0a.png) on Linux Foundation.

Also as answered by [dr01](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434057/259047), you can have a crisp knowledge about it at [Wikipedia : FileSystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Would like to add this beautiful image from this **[Source](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ab/06/70/ab0670ef648900b04d7a37d7a5b5ba0a.png)**. I reference this image every now and then. But please note that *none* of the directories should be capitalized.

[image: File System Hierarchy]

Feel free to add-in more details.

Comment: This is the most attractive infographic except for the highly misleading use of SHOUTING CAPITAL LETTERS.

Comment: @Rich Not only SHOUTING and misleading, it's actually incorrect, as `/USR` isn't the same as `/usr`.  And `/usr` is correct...

Comment: I just noticed it's also missing `/lost+found`, `/net`, `/proc` and `/sys`. There's an update at that URL that includes `/proc`, `/media`, and `/srv`, but it's still ALLCAPS, and it's still missing `/lost+found`, `/net`, and `/sys`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I gave the author a prod on his blog there :-) I'd really like to print this out.

Answer (score 4):

The **Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)**, maintained by the Linux Foundation, defines the filesystem hierarchy and directory structure and contents in all Linux distributions.

It is described here: [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

Answer (score 1):

You can also read the man page of `hier` which display each directory and its job.

```
$ man hier
NAME
       hier - description of the filesystem hierarchy

DESCRIPTION
       A typical Linux system has, among others, the following directories:

       /      This  is  the  root  directory.   This  is  where the whole tree
              starts.

       /bin   This directory contains executable programs which are needed  in
              single user mode and to bring the system up or repair it.
............
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some help.It gives a basic overview of the how directories and files exist in linux File System[image]